# What is different `./` and `.\`?

Tags: windows, command-prompt

**NOTICE**

*I tried to find the answer of it. but searching for `difference ./ and .\` did result nothing*

*Instead of answering on this question, it'd be also helpful that you let me know how to search for this subject*

---

#### Question

- What is different `./` and `.\`?

#### Description

- while using `Command Prompt` I found that file locations sometimes can be written from `./`

  - ex) `mspaint ./Apple.png`
- and the locations that use `./` can be replaced by `.\`

  - ex) results of using `mspaint ./Apple.png` and `mspaint .\Apple.png` are the same
- in inverse case, it cannot

  - ex) `.\mspaint.exe` → it works well
  - ex) `./mspaint.exe` → error with `'.' is not recognized as an internal ... batch file`

Comment: In DOS and Microsoft Windows, the path separator character is \; you talk about `C:\WINDOWS\System32\ftp.exe`. However, in most cases the OS also recognizes `/`. [In DOS and Windows, `/` is used for command-line switches. In Unix/Linux, `/` is the path separator character.] Knowing this, you realize that .\ is simply the current directory (since that is what a single period means -- `..` is the parent directory).

Comment: thank you I got understood of this subject !